# C# Winform: How to set the Base Color of a TabControl (not the tabpage) AND use an icon

Tags: c#, winforms

I applied the solution provided by an user to solve the problem, but it's happening another problem. Previously I owned an icon along with the text, but after I used the code described here, my icon no longer appears. What can it be?

And how can I use the icon while using a different color other than the default on tab header?

The solution I used is:

```
private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {

            TabPage CurrentTab = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];
            Rectangle ItemRect = tabControl1.GetTabRect(e.Index);
            SolidBrush FillBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            SolidBrush TextBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

            //If we are currently painting the Selected TabItem we'll
            //change the brush colors and inflate the rectangle.
            if (System.Convert.ToBoolean(e.State & DrawItemState.Selected))
            {
                FillBrush.Color = Color.White;
                TextBrush.Color = Color.Red;
                ItemRect.Inflate(2, 2);
            }

            //Set up rotation for left and right aligned tabs
            if (tabControl1.Alignment == TabAlignment.Left || tabControl1.Alignment == TabAlignment.Right)
            {
                float RotateAngle = 90;
                if (tabControl1.Alignment == TabAlignment.Left)
                    RotateAngle = 270;
                PointF cp = new PointF(ItemRect.Left + (ItemRect.Width / 2), ItemRect.Top + (ItemRect.Height / 2));
                e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(cp.X, cp.Y);
                e.Graphics.RotateTransform(RotateAngle);
                ItemRect = new Rectangle(-(ItemRect.Height / 2), -(ItemRect.Width / 2), ItemRect.Height, ItemRect.Width);
            }

            //Next we'll paint the TabItem with our Fill Brush
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(FillBrush, ItemRect);

            //Now draw the text.
            e.Graphics.DrawString(CurrentTab.Text, e.Font, TextBrush, (RectangleF)ItemRect, sf);

            //Reset any Graphics rotation
            e.Graphics.ResetTransform();


            //Finally, we should Dispose of our brushes.
            FillBrush.Dispose();
            TextBrush.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: The code is missing the required Graphics.DrawImage() call to draw the icon.  So of course you don't see an icon.

Answer (score 0):

You need to paint the Icon yourself also. An example would be to add something like the following after the painting of the tabs Background in you code (i assume that an image list was used here)

```
int imageLeftOffset = 4;
Point imagePos = new Point(imageLeftOffset, ItemRect.Top + (ItemRect.Height - tabControl1.ImageList.ImageSize.Height + 1) / 2);
tabControl1.ImageList.Draw(e.Graphics, imagePos, CurrentTab.ImageIndex);
```

You may need to reajust the drawing of the Text so that text and image aren't overlapping.